# Set the layout weight of a TextView programmatically

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to dynamically create `TableRow` objects and add them to a `TableLayout`.
The `TableRow` objects has 2 items, a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`. The `TextView` items need to have their layout weight set to 1 to push the `CheckBox` items to the far right.

I can't find documentation on how to programmatically set the layout weight of a `TextView` item.

Answer (score 365):

You have to use `TableLayout.LayoutParams` with something like this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

The last parameter is the weight.

Comment: I didn't mention this before, so I'm sorry. But I tried this prior to asking my question. It makes the TextView disappear from the layout. But, on a positive note, I found that setting the stretch_columns property of the TableLayout to 0 causes the effect I'm looking for (TextView's on the left, CheckBoxes on the right).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are importing an XML layout and you are not creating your layout dynamically, you can grab it like this: `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_inside_the_linearlayout);  tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));`

Comment: To set the layout weight programmatically, `TableRow.LayoutParams` should be used instead of `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. See @Dorje's answer.

Comment: import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;

Comment: table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

Answer (score 101):

The answer is that you have to use TableRow.LayoutParams, not LinearLayout.LayoutParams or any other LayoutParams.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The different LayoutParams are not interchangeable and if you use the wrong one then nothing seems to happen.  The text view's parent is a table row, hence:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html

Comment: This answer helped me a lot...TableLayout did not worked for me

Comment: Aw man, you saved me so much time. Where is it specified? I found nothing in documentation about you cannot interchange `LayoutParams`

Comment: `TableRow.LayoutParams` did the job for me too

Comment: The key part of this answer is the 0

Comment: It will reduce my work time.Im searching for this for a long time.Very great solution

Answer (score 41):

In the earlier answers *weight* is passed to the constructor of a new SomeLayoutType.LayoutParams object.
Still in many cases it's more convenient to use existing objects - it helps to avoid dealing with parameters we are not interested in.

An example:

```
// Get our View (TextView or anything) object:
View v = findViewById(R.id.our_view); 

// Get params:
LinearLayout.LayoutParams loparams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

// Set only target params:
loparams.height = 0;
loparams.weight = 1;
v.setLayoutParams(loparams);
```

Comment: loparams could be NULL so make sure you check that before calling setLayoutParams()

Comment: @AAgg, not in a practical situation. View wouldn't have inflated if it hadn't width and height set. But I agree -  it's a good practice to check when there're doubts about null.

Answer (score 17):

```
TextView txtview = new TextView(v.getContext());
LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
txtview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

1f is denotes as weight=1; you can give 2f or 3f, views will move accoding to the space

Answer (score 13):

just set layout params in that layout like

create param variable

```
 android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
```

1f is weight variable

set your widget or layout like

```
 TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
 text.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: where do you get this information that 1f means the weight variable ? Can you provide a link please ?

Comment: @hayonj just check sources of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` constructor. 3rd parameter is weight. Or [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 11):

```
TextView text = new TextView(v.getContext());
text.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

(OR)

```
TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

1f is refered as weight=1; according to your need you can give 2f or 3f, views will move accoding to the space. For making specified distance between views in Linear layout use **weightsum** for "LinearLayout".

```
LinearLayout ll_Outer= (LinearLayout ) view.findViewById(R.id.linearview);
LinearLayout llInner = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            llInner.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            llInner.WeightSum = 2;
            ll_Outer.AddView(llInner);
```

Answer (score 10):

This  should works to you

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

param.weight=1.0f;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also give weight separately like this  ,

```
LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

 lp1.weight=1;
```

Answer (score 6):

This work for me, and I hope it will work for you also

Set the LayoutParams for the parent view first:

```
myTableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

then set for the TextView (child):

```
 TableLayout.LayoutParams textViewParam = new TableLayout.LayoutParams
     (TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
     //-- set components margins
     textViewParam.setMargins(5, 0, 5,0);
     myTextView.setLayoutParams(textViewParam);
```

Answer (score 2):

After strugling for 4 hours.
Finally, This code worked for me.

3 Columns are there in a row.

```
  TextView serialno = new TextView(UsersActivity.this);
  TextView userId = new TextView(UsersActivity.this);
  TextView name = new TextView(UsersActivity.this);

  serialno.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
  userId.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
  name.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this. In case you need to set only one parameter, for example 'height':

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a fair amount of difficulty with a solution something very similar to this: trying to have two buttons in a TableRow, with each being half the screen width.  For whatever reason, the left button would always be about 70% of the width, and the right button 30%.  Calling table_layout.setStretchAllColumns(true) had no effect, nor did setting the button's width to half the screen, nor setting their layout weight.

The solution I ended up with was nesting a LinearLayout in the TableRows, which *did* take into account the value of the buttons' width.

```
    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow top_row = new TableRow(this);
    left_button = styleButton();
    right_button = styleButton();
    LinearLayout toprow_layout = new LinearLayout (this);
    toprow_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    toprow_layout.addView (left_button);
    toprow_layout.addView(right_button);
    toprow.addView(top_layout);
    layout.addView(top_row)

    private Button styleButton() {
            Button btn = new Button (this);
            android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();      
            btn.setWidth((int)(display.getWidth()/2));    // set width to half
            btn.setHeight(((int)display.getHeight()/6));  // set height to whatevs
            btn.setText("foo");
            return btn;
        }
```

Comment: Just so you know for the future, the solution is to set the TableRow, Button1, and Button2 to all have `layout_width=fill_parent`, and after doing that, set the `layout_weight=1` for both button1 and button2.  All elements with fill_parent and a layout_weight=1 will be given an equal size upon inflation.