# how to set the Style Attribute Programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I have to set the style for a `TextView` which is created programmatically.

**How do I implement `style="@style/test"` programmatically?**

I have looked at the [Android developer style documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) already, but it did not answer my question. Any ideas?

Comment: you can refer to this answer on stack overflow
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224365/1769515

Comment: Is this supported now ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Dynamic style change is not currently supported. You must set the style before the view is create (in xml).

Comment: what class i have to use for that?

Comment: You just put style="@style/test" in the definition for your TextView in the layout xml file.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the style to view's constructor. This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Use `ContextThemeWrapper` and setup your style as a Theme for it:

   ```
   ContextThemeWrapper wrappedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(yourContext, R.style.test);
   TextView testView = new TextView(wrappedContext, null, 0);
   ```

And important note here - to properly set the style with `ContextThemeWrapper` we have to use three-argument constructor and set `defStyleAttr` parameter to 0. Otherwise the default button style will be applied to the view.

2. Starting from API 21 we can use constructor with 4 parameters:

   ```
   View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
   ```

Where `defStyleRes` is your style ID

With the same remark - defStyleAttr should be 0

Answer (score 3):

```
setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

It works for me