# Applying Android Dialog Animations?

Tags: android, xml, animation, dialog

I want to set animation to my Dialog.  The challenge here is that I want to do this programatically.

The reason for that is I have too many different size of dialogs and I don't want to create a new `animation` file for each type of dialog.

As of now, this if what I am doing:

**`res/anim/anim_myDialog_SlideUp.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false">

   <translate android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="200%" 
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

**`res/anim/anim_myDialog_SlideDown.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false">

   <translate android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0" 
        android:toYDelta="200%"
        android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

**In my `res/values/styles.xml` file:**

```
<style name="slideUpAndDown">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_myDialog_SlideUp</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_myDialog_SlideDown</item>
</style>

<style name="myDialogSlideUpAndDown" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/slideUpAndDown</item>
</style>
```

**In my `MainActivity.cs` file:**

```
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this, Resource.Style.myDialogSlideUpAndDown);
```

I can create the animations programmatically with no problem.  The problem is how can I set those animations to my Dialog?

If I create a `Dialog` and not set it's style in the constructor:

```
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);
```

Then I have the option to do this to set it's animation:

```
myDialog.Window.SetWindowAnimations(int);
```

`SetWindowAnimations` requires an `int`.  Can I create this animation `int` manually?

Sorry for the long explanation and thank you for your time.

Comment: try : `mDialog.Window.SetWindowAnimations(R.anim.anim_myDialog_SlideUp) // for slide up animtion `

Comment: That will work but only for enter animation.  That's the main problem.  `SetWindowAnimations` only takes 1 int.

Comment: What you are asking is to create an animation resource dynamically which is not possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499770/applying-style-resource-programatically

Comment: got it.  I guess I will have to create new `anim` file for each type of dialog.  Thanks.