# Android ActionBar with custom layout does not occupy whole width of parent

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my xml fil

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="#fff556ff"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_relativelayout"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_dashboard" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgMenu"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgMenu"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgUser"
        android:layout_width="40dp"

        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgUser"
        android:src="@drawable/message_dashboard"
     />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
        android:layout_width="40dp"

        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my  Activity

```
 RelativeLayout custom_RelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_relativelayout);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM );
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.drawable_actionbar_back));
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
```

I want to its occupy whole space of action bar but it does not occupy i also read many answers on stackoverflow but didn't work.
1) I want match parent space in action bar

Edit This is my main Avtivity

```
package com.example.qasim.cashmanagement;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class DashboardActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    View viewAction;
    ImageView imgUserbutton;// Actionbar
    ImageView imgMessagebutton;// Actionbar
    ImageView imgInfobutton;// Action bar
    ImageView imgMenubutton;// Actionbar

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_two);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
       GetActionBarDetails();// Method for inflating ActionBar

/*
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);*/

      /*  ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        View actionBarView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView, lp);*/
     //  actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

    /*   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.drawable_actionbar_back));

        viewAction = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    private void GetActionBarDetails()
    {

       RelativeLayout custom_RelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_relativelayout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM );
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.drawable_actionbar_back));
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
        imgUserbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgUser);
        imgInfobutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgInfo);
        imgMessagebutton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMessage);
        imgMenubutton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMenu);
        imgMenubutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgMessagebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgInfobutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgUserbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I also read this post and apply also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783381/actionbar-with-custom-layout-does-not-occupy-full-screen-width-on-android-4-4-2

Comment: why dont you use toolbar

Comment: I read also toolbar widget but it more difficult then this

Comment: Whats wrong in this code ?

Comment: Help me plz I am stuck on this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the height of native action bar then use `?android:attr/actionBarSize` in XML.

Now your XML will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#fff556ff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgUser"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is the main key point  android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: its resolve my height problem but my main problem is width cant occupy match parent

Comment: no application crashed and says you need Them.app.compat .

Comment: i want width  of native action bar .

Comment: sorry sir i check this but still width not native

Comment: sorry sir i am wasting your time but i am stuck on this

Comment: i also add my whole activity class in my question