# i want to change the color of swipe tab in viewpager

Tags: android

i want to change the background color of the swipe tab by using viewpager.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: see more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335267/how-to-customize-individual-tabs-changing-background-color-indicator-color-an

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to custom your viewpager tab bar.
Here is very useful library for setting viewpager tabs: [PagerSlidingTabTrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

It's better than android default viewpager tab bar.

Example xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/mobi.thevip"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C0C0" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar_line"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height"
        app1:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator"
        app1:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/tab_underline_indicator" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/indicator" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can read *library Readme* to use it.

Hope this help!

Comment: is it the background color of the swipe tab is depend on app theme....is it possible to change the tab background color if i change the theme color.

Comment: @Ajaz: Background of the swipe tab, I think it can be changed like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335267/how-to-customize-individual-tabs-changing-background-color-indicator-color-an

Thank you, Johnson  - for this link! :)