# TabLayout update tab content with a custom view

Tags: android, tabs, android-design-library

I'm using `TabLayout` of the new material design and i have a problem, i can't update tab content of a custom view once the tab is created:

I can simplify my method inside my PagerAdapter with

```
public View setTabView(int position, boolean selected) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.default_tab_view, null);
    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tabTextView);
    if(selected)
        tv.setText("SELECTED");
    else 
        tv.setText("UNSELECTED");       
    return v;
}
```

And in activity i can simplify my code with:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    boolean isFirstTab = i == 0;
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    View v;
    v = adapter.setTabView(i, isFirstTab);
    v.setSelected(isFirstTab);
    tab.setCustomView(v);
}

tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        adapter.setTabView(tab.getPosition(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        adapter.setTabView(tab.getPosition(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

The tabs' titles are set right when the app starts but when i change tab, the content still remains the same.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Ok **I think it's bug on android design support library v22.**

Because You are talking about the changes in content but I can't change the color of Text. Once the tab are created and if you change the layout it will not reflecting.

And As i have seen your code you are giving the custom layout using setCustomView. and for changing a text you are calling again the method setTabView(). Instead of that there should be method getCustomView() so that you can change the layout. There is a method in a TabLayout.Tab.getCustomView but it doesn't have identifier and I have report this bug.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177492

**[Update 08-07-2015]**

Finally bug is accepted by android bug source traking and marked as **Future Release** . So we can say that bug will no more exist on future library.
and we can have method `getCustomView()` so that we can easily get our custom view.

**[Update 18-08-2015]**

Finally the bug is resolved Released in the **v23 support libs** .
Just update support library using SDK manager and you have getCustomView() as a public.

just change this line in gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

and make sure compile and target sdk set to 23.

> please check my code working fine for me

```
TabLayout.Tab tab=tabLayout.getTabAt(position);         
View view=tab.getCustomView();         
TextView txtCount= (TextView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);         
txtCount.setText(count+"");
```

Comment: Perfect, i'll follow it.

Comment: @Moinkhan you can set view as tag to tablayout.

Comment: Ok i understand what you are saying but finally the bug is accepted and solved by google. Now status for this bug is future release. So we don't have to do any tricky solution..

Comment: @Moinkhan How  we can get the latest update v23 support libs in android studio.i installed the version and tool but when try to change in the gradle file i am getting error.Please suggest solution

Comment: yes, it works! but a little strange, on android developer website (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) still show the newest version is 22.2.0

Comment: Have you checked it properly ... they are showing 23.0.1 ....with list of bug which are resolved ..

Comment: I'm sorry but, how to use this getCustomView() again?

Comment: Thank you so much @Moinkhan..!! the library support:design 22 had this bug and had consumed a lot of my time..

Answer (score 7):

Well ok, I might have found a very tricky solution just because I didn't have any time to wait for next support-library version. Here's what I did:

1. Set pager adapter to your TabLayout `tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(pagerAdapter);`
2. Add listener to your ViewPager

   ```
       customViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
       }
   });
   ```
3. Add listener to your TabLayout

   ```
   tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new
   TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
           if (!isTabUpdating) {
               isTabUpdating = true;
               final int pos = tab.getPosition();
               customViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

               // Clears and populates all tabs
               tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(pagerAdapter);
               invalidateTabs(pos);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
           if (!isTabUpdating) {
               isTabUpdating = true;
               final int pos = tab.getPosition();
               customViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

               // Clears and populates all tabs
               tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(pagerAdapter);
               invalidateTabs(pos);
           }
       }
   });
   ```
4. Add method for re-drawing all tabs

   ```
   private void invalidateTabs(int selected) {
     for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
         tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i, i == selected));
     }
     isTabUpdating = false;
   }
   ```

Ok, so let me explain know a little bit. First of all, you might wonder why did I used `setTabsFromPagerAdapter()` instead of `setupWithViewPager`. In the beginning I used `setupWithViewPager` but somehow my it didn't work correctly with my pager and the 1st item wasn't been able to be selected.

The second thing you might admit - every time I'm selecting a tab I'm deleting all of them. Well, that was kind of easy problem, you see I android sources when you call `Tab.setCustomView(View)` it checks the parent of the view and if it's not null - it removes all childviews. However if you pass newly-instantiated item you'll ADD another view instead of replacing the old one:

```
    View custom = tab.getCustomView();
        if(custom != null) {
            ViewParent icon = custom.getParent();
            if(icon != this) {
                if(icon != null) {
                    // You wont get here
                    ((ViewGroup)icon).removeView(custom);
                }

                this.addView(custom);
            }
     ...
```

So, I ended up with setting all listeners by myself and re-creating all tabs every time on page/tab changes. That's NOT good solution, but as far as can't wait for Google to update their lib - this's probably the only solution to achieve such effect. *(Just in case you're wondering why is this so complicated - I needed to have Tabs with custom views (text + image) which could change their view-properties (font color, image) when they're selected/unselected)*

BTW - Here's the `getTabView(...)` method from 4th step:

```
public View getTabView(int pos, boolean isSeleted) {
    View tabview = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout
                    .tab_sessioninfo,
            null, false);
    final ImageView ivTabIcon = (ImageView) tabview.findViewById(R.id.iv_tab_icon);
    final TextView tvTabTittle = (TextView) tabview.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_title);

    if (isSeleted) {
        tvTabTittle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_indicator));
    }

    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            tvTabTittle.setText("1st Tab");
            ivTabIcon.setImageResource(isSeleted ? R.drawable.ic_icon1_selected : R.drawable.ic_icon1);
            break;

        case 1:
            tvTabTittle.setText("2nd Tab");
            ivTabIcon.setImageResource(isSeleted ? R.drawable.ic_icon2_selected : R.drawable.ic_icon2);
            break;

        case 2:
            tvTabTittle.setText("3rd Tab");
            ivTabIcon.setImageResource(isSeleted ? R.drawable.ic_icon3_selected : R.drawable.ic_icon3);
            break;
    }

    return tabview;
}
```

P.S. If you know better solution for all this stuff let me know!

**UPDATE**

Better solution could be approached by using Reflection:

1. Easy setup

   ```
   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(customViewPager);
   customViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           for (int i = 0; i <tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++){
               updateTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(i), position == i);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
       }
   });
   ```
2. Update Tab

   ```
   private void updateTab(TabLayout.Tab tab, boolean isSelected){
     Method method = null;
     try {
         method = TabLayout.Tab.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCustomView", null);
         method.setAccessible(true);

         View tabview = (View) method.invoke(tab, null);

         final ImageView ivTabIcon = (ImageView) tabview.findViewById(R.id.iv_tab_icon);
         final TextView tvTabTittle = (TextView) tabview.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_title);

         if (isSeleted) {
             tvTabTittle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_indicator));
         }

         switch (pos) {
         case 0:
               tvTabTittle.setText("1st Tab");
               ivTabIcon.setImageResource(isSeleted ? R.drawable.ic_icon1_selected : R.drawable.ic_icon1);
               break;

         case 1:
               tvTabTittle.setText("2nd Tab");
               ivTabIcon.setImageResource(isSeleted ? R.drawable.ic_icon2_selected : R.drawable.ic_icon2);
               break;

         case 2:
               tvTabTittle.setText("3rd Tab");
               ivTabIcon.setImageResource(isSeleted ? R.drawable.ic_icon3_selected : R.drawable.ic_icon3);
               break;
         }

         tab.setCustomView(tabview);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE**

New support library has public method for `getCustomView()`, so you don't need reflection no more!

Comment: I don't have any layout for tab, i just used library. so how can I bind the component  "final ImageView ivTabIcon = (ImageView) tabview.findViewById(R.id.iv_tab_icon); ", where I need to add custom layout?

Comment: @Tara, Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using direct library not defining any custom layout for tab As you defined " R.layout.tab_sessioninfo" . If i am not using any custom layout so i will not be having any ImageView. My agenda was upon clicking a tab that tab icon gets changed. Some what like before selecting a tab its icon was gray and upon selecting icon changes to blue. Any how I solved my problem by adding "addOnPageChangeListener and onPageSelected" methods.

Answer (score 0):

> please check my code working fine for me

```
TabLayout.Tab tab=tabLayout.getTabAt(position);         
View view=tab.getCustomView();         
TextView txtCount= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);         
txtCount.setText(count+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the   [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335267/how-to-customize-individual-tabs-changing-background-color-indicator-color-an/40400544#40400544)   you need to set the layout as expected by you. If you want to change the Tab Content then make changes in Tab.setOnTabSelectedListener()

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        if(tab.getPosition()==1){
                tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.unselected_tab),ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.tab_selection));
            }else{
                tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.unselected_tab),ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));

            }

 // same thing goes with other tabs too
 // Just change your tab text on selected/deselected as above

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tab.setCustomView(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Documents are very poor on this topic. We can use `setCustomView` method of tabs to set custom view. Following is a working example without any need of creating custom adapters:

**tab_layout.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark" />
```

**custom_tab_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/tab_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabTitle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_item)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tabIcon)
                        ?.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab1)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tabTitle)?.setText(R.string.tab1)
                }
                1 -> {
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_item)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tabIcon)
                        ?.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab2)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tabTitle)
                        ?.setText(R.string.tab2)
                }
            }
        }.attach()
```