# getCustomView() of TabLayout.Tab is not public in Design Library

Tags: java, android, android-design-library

I am using the Google Design Library v**22.2.0**. I have used the TabLayout with ViewPager using custom view for tabs.

After getting location, I have to update the Title of custom tab view.
This was the 1st option I tried to update it:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setText("Location");
```

But this removes the Custom View & sets normal Text.

I looked at the references of **TabLayout.Tab**  [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#getCustomView%28%29) & found that there's a function named **public View getCustomView()**.

Tried the same thing in Studio & it says that the function is not **public**.

Does anybody else is facing the same issue. If yes, where should I report this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug on Android design support library, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911250/tablayout-update-tab-content-with-a-custom-view)

Just change this line in gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

and make sure compile and target sdk set to 23.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. It's added later after releasing the library in this [commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/21f887ec48f1e9780a69833723e1fba64e7557c5) you just need to update the version of the library to the recent one. It has been public from version 23.0.0.