# How can I change tab background of TabLayout in Android?

Tags: android, colors, tabs, android-design-library

I am using a `TabLayout` to switch between three tabs in my Android application. Each of the tabs contains a `ListView` with people information (that I've hidden in this screenshot).

[image: screenshot of current result]

I would like to know if there is a way to have a different background for each tab? I'm not talking about the background of the fragment here, but the background behind "TAB1" "TAB2" and "TAB3".

For example, i want something like that:

[image: wanted result]

I already tried to set a custom view and change its background, like this:

```
TabLayout.Tab memberTab = tabLayout.newTab();
memberTab.setText(R.string.tromb_tab1_title);
View v = new View(this);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
memberTab.setCustomView(v);
```

But it only changes the color above the text "TAB1" and not the "tab rectangle" as a whole:

[image: first try result]

What can I do to obtain what I want?

Comment: visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335267/how-to-customize-individual-tabs-changing-background-color-indicator-color-an