# Style for custom view extended from ToggleButton set programatically

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-styles

I extend from ToggleButton and wanna set my style. Everything works correctly when I set style in xml like `style="@style/Button.Filter.Text"`
but when I set style programatically in constructor in custom ToggleButton like `super(context, attrs, R.style.Button_Filter_Text);` my buttons are styled like normal TextView (probably without style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set style programmatically, the good way is to set style in xml and then inflate it. Take a look in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code) to confirm and [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051753/how-do-i-apply-a-style-programmatically) which describes more ways to do that.
And [one more example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335239/android-toggle-button-custom-look).

Comment: in this case my Custom Button has to be ViewGroup, because I should add somewhere this inflated ToggleButton. Am I understand correctly? It's quite ugly that I produce unnecessery view layer and structure of my code need to be changed only because of this styling issue.

Comment: no `Button` is a `View` and you will have to add it to parent, `ViewGroup`. This is ugly I agree. Also if I understood purpose properly you can make a `selector` in `drawable` and set some style as background. This is from "second one" answer.

Comment: Ok, I changed structure of my custom view and wrap ToggleButton into FrameLayout ugly, but versatile in this case. Cheers for info that I can't do it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter `int defStyleAttr` in three-argument constructor may not work with the custom styles. From the Android documentation:

> **defStyleAttr** - An attribute in the current theme that contains a reference to a style resource that supplies default values for the
>   view. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.

To workaround this case use such approach:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrappedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(yourContext, R.style.Button_Filter_Text);
View view = new View(wrappedContext, null, 0);
```

Or if you support just LOLLIPOP and higher there is a     use constructor with 4 parameters:

```
View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

Where `defStyleAttr` should be 0 and `defStyleRes` is your style ID