# How to get resource identifier of styles.xml file?

Tags: android, resources, cordova-plugins

I want resource id of style file at runtime because I can able to access current package of application

here is styles.xml file

```
<style name="CustomDigitsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#ff398622</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff398622</item>
</style>
```

and fro with this code snippet I am trying to fetch my customtheme

```
int styleId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("CustomDigitsTheme", "styles",getActivity().getPackageName());
```

but it returns 0. So is there any other way to get style resource .

I need runtime resource because I am making cordova plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply a style programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051753/how-do-i-apply-a-style-programmatically)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate of mentioned link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change `styles` to `style` (R.**style**.CustomDigitsTheme):

`int styleId = getResources().getIdentifier("CustomDigitsTheme", "style", getPackageName());`

Comment: how do we refer the name if the style name is "Custom.DigitsTheme" should we write the name as Custom_DigitsTheme?

Comment: sorry my bad, there was a mistake in the name I defined