# Android - set TextView TextStyle programmatically?

Tags: java, android, textview

Is there a way to set the `textStyle` attribute of a `TextView` programmatically? There doesn't appear to be a `setTextStyle()` method.

To be clear, I am not talking about View / Widget styles! I am talking about the following:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/my_text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Hello World"
  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: you can reference below link, and lock top 1 answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic

Comment: Please check my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40802895/1252158). Hope this will help you

Answer (score 524, accepted):

```
textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

setTypeface is the Attribute textStyle.

As *Shankar V* added, to preserve the previously set typeface attributes you can use:

```
textview.setTypeface(textview.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: it should be `textview.setTypeface(textview.getTypeface(), Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);`

Comment: @IlyaEremin to preserve the previously set font you need to use it like this.

Comment: Edited my answer based on @SankarV comment.

Comment: I think you should loose the DEFAULT:
holder.title.setTypeface(holder.title.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

Comment: Actually `textview.getTypeface().getStyle()` is `android:textStyle`

Answer (score 177):

Let's say you have a style called RedHUGEText on your values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="RedHUGEText" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_huge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Just create your TextView as usual in the XML layout/your_layout.xml file, let's say:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_view_title" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content 
    android:text="FOO" />
```

And in the java code of your Activity you do this:

```
TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.RedHUGEText);
```

It worked for me! And it applied color, size, gravity, etc. I've used it on handsets and tablets with Android API Levels from 8 to 17 with no problems. Note that as of Android 23, that method has been deprecated. The context argument has been dropped, so the last line would need to be:

```
textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(R.style.RedHUGEText);
```

**To support all API levels use androidX `TextViewCompat`**

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textViewTitle, R.style.RedHUGEText)
```

Remember... this is useful only if the style of the text really depends on a condition on your Java logic or you are building the UI "on the fly" with code... if it doesn't, it is better to just do:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_view_title" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content 
    android:text="FOO" 
    style="@style/RedHUGEText" />
```

You can always have it your way!

Comment: This will only set a subset of attributes that can be defined in a `<style>` tag. It does the common ones (size, color, style), but doesn't apply others (including padding, background, gravity, etc)

Comment: Seems to require min API 23?

Comment: there are two methods, one for api < 23, and one for api 23+.  They appear identical except the one for <23 takes a context argument and the one for 23+ does not. 

Under the hood, the one for api 23+ calls the method for <23 and uses the member context for the textview.

Answer (score 69):

Search for `setTextAppearance` or also `setTextTypeface`. There is similar question on stackoverflow: [How to change a TextView's style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime)

Comment: setTextAppearance deprecated api level 23

Comment: there is a new method for api 23+ that just doesn't take a context argument.

Answer (score 61):

So many way to achieve this task some are below:-

**1.**

```
String text_view_str = "<b>Bolded text</b>, <i>italic text</i>, even <u>underlined</u>!";
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ur_text_view_id);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text_view_str));
```

**2.**

```
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

**3.**

```
SpannableString spannablecontent=new SpannableString(o.content.toString());
spannablecontent.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), 
                         0,spannablecontent.length(), 0);
// set Text here
tt.setText(spannablecontent);
```

**4.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="boldText">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="normalText">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#C0C0C0</item>
    </style>

</resources>

 tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
```

**or if u want through xml**

```
android:textStyle="normal"
android:textStyle="normal|bold"
android:textStyle="normal|italic"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

Comment: setTextAppearance() is the answer I was after in order to apply a custom style defined in my XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

### • `Kotlin Version`

To retain current font in addition to text style:

```
textView.apply {
    setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL)
    // or
    setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.BOLD)
    // or
    setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.ITALIC)
    // or
    setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This question is asked in a lot of places in a lot of different ways. I originally answered it here but I feel it's relevant in this thread as well (since i ended up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051753/how-do-i-apply-a-style-programmatically/19690509#19690509) when I was searching for an answer).

There is no one line solution to this problem, but this worked for my use case. The problem is, the 'View(context, attrs, defStyle)' constructor does not refer to an actual style, it wants an attribute. So, we will:

1. Define an attribute
2. Create a style that you want to use
3. Apply a style for that attribute on our theme
4. Create new instances of our view with that attribute

In 'res/values/attrs.xml', define a new attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="customTextViewStyle" format="reference"/>
    ...
</resources>
```

In res/values/styles.xml' I'm going to create the style I want to use on my custom TextView

```
<style name="CustomTextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">14dp</item>
</style>
```

In 'res/values/themes.xml' or 'res/values/styles.xml', modify the theme for your application / activity and add the following style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="@attr/customTextViewStyle">@style/CustomTextView</item>
    </style>
    ... 
</resources>
```

Finally, in your custom TextView, you can now use the constructor with the attribute and it will receive your style

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
       super(context, null, R.attr.customTextView);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that I repeatedly used customTextView in different variants and different places, but it is in no way required that the name of the view match the style or the attribute or anything. Also, this technique should work with any custom view, not just TextViews.

Answer (score 7):

Since `setTextAppearance(resId)` is only available for API 23 and above, use:

`TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textViewGoesHere, resId)`

This method is internally implemented as follows:

```
public static void setTextAppearance(@NonNull TextView textView, @StyleRes int resId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        textView.setTextAppearance(resId);
    } else {
        textView.setTextAppearance(textView.getContext(), resId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
textview.setTypeface(textview.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

or

```
textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Answer (score 3):

I´ve resolved it with two simple methods.

Follow the explanation.

My existing style declaration:

```
<style name="SearchInfoText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Church_Grey</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/Shadow_Church</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">3</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
</style>
```

My Android Java code:

```
    TextView locationName = new TextView(getSupportActivity());
    locationName.setId(IdGenerator.generateViewId());
    locationName.setText(location.getName());
    locationName.setLayoutParams(super.centerHorizontal());
    locationName.setTextSize(24f);
    locationName.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 15);
    locationName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Church_Grey));
    locationName.setShadowLayer(3, 1, 1,  getResources().getColor(R.color.Shadow_Church));
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this one

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.Lato_Bold);
            } else {
                textView.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.Lato_Bold);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin extension function for `changing style without changing typeface`:

```
fun TextView.setTextStyle(style: Int) {
    typeface = when (style) {
        Typeface.NORMAL,
        Typeface.BOLD,
        Typeface.ITALIC,
        Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC -> Typeface.create(typeface, style)

        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid text style. Use NORMAL, BOLD, ITALIC, or BOLD_ITALIC")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
textView.setTextStyle(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246447/how-to-set-the-style-attribute-programmatically-in-android/3246458#3246458), this feature is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

This Works For Me

```
msg.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
OR
TextView.setTypeface(msg.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Instead Off

```
TextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data binding and Kotlin

```
@BindingAdapter("textViewStyle")
fun TextView.bindTextViewStyle(styleResourceId: Int) {
    TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(this, styleResourceId)
}
```

XML

```
 <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="test text"
   bind:textViewStyle="@{styleResId}" />
```