# How do I set the style of a textView programmatically?

Tags: android, styles, textview, android-styles

I'm creating a textView programmatically. Is there a way that i can set the style of this textView? Something similar to

```
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
```

which I would use if I had a `layout.xml` file.

Comment: you can not set the style of any view pragmatically. but you can set individual properties of the view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - set TextView TextStyle programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919173/android-set-textview-textstyle-programmatically)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can't programmatically set the style of a View, but you might be able to do something like `textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);`.

Comment: Use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
} else {
    textView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
}`

Comment: To simplify @Nedko's solution you can use: `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tv, styleResource);`

Answer (score 34):

It is not currently possible to set the style of a View programatically.

To get around this you can create a template layout xml file with the style assigned, for example in `res/layout` create `tvtemplate.xml` as with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a template"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small" />
```

then inflate this to instantiate your new TextView:

```
TextView myText = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tvtemplate, null);
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted answer since it supports style as the OP requested (and I wanted). Besides, it always feels so....wrong.... to use an android.widget constructor.

Answer (score 16):

Actually, this is possible as of API level 21.

TextView has a [4 parameter constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int)):

```
TextView (Context context, 
          AttributeSet attrs, 
          int defStyleAttr, 
          int defStyleRes)
```

The middle two parameters are not necessary in this case. The following code creates a TextView directly in an activity and only defines its style resource:

```
TextView myStyledTextView = new TextView(this, null, 0, R.style.my_style);
```

Answer (score 8):

Compat version (because of deprecation in api 23):

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
textview.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.yourstyle);
```

this may not work try Creating an xml with the textview like this

```
textviewstyle.xml

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small" />
```

To get the desired style inflate the xml that contains textview

```
TextView myText = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tvstyle, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Views generated at run time ( in code ) you may pass style to constructor: [View(Context, AttributeSet, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29)

In other case you have to call varios methods to change apperance

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
```

is deprecated in java so use it without context for kotlin

```
textView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Deprecated
public void setTextAppearance(Context context, @StyleRes int resId)
```

This method is deprecated as of Android SDK 23.

You can use safe version:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    super.setTextAppearance(context, resId);
} else {
    super.setTextAppearance(resId);
}
```