# As for the TextView, programmatically change the style?

Tags: android, textview

For example:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(PhotoActivity.this);
textView.setText("Photo not found.");
```

How to set the style?

```
textView.set... ???
```

Comment: check (Related Method) next to (XML Attributes) in the android docs for textview http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: Search on google .Too old question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - set TextView TextStyle programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919173/android-set-textview-textstyle-programmatically)

Comment: Please accept an answer and I will come back to upvote the question; many people have offered good information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all , I found the solution I need .

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

TextView textView = new TextView(PhotoActivity.this);
textView.setText("Photo not found.");
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

As an alternative way:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: if this your answer and solution than question should "How to set TextColor dynamically ? " not how to set Style ?

Comment: in which multiverse does this change the style as stated in "As for the TextView, programmatically change the style?" ????

Comment: well the answer doesnt match the question at all

Answer (score 20):

For styling `TextView` programmatically you must have a style inheriting a `TextAppearance` style, and you can apply it using the following:

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(statusLinkTextView, R.style.YourTextAppearanceStyle);
```

Answer (score 8):

For styling you can use from following these options:

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the most simple and effective.

Comment: This changes the Typeface, _not_ the style.

Answer (score 6):

You can change TextView Style by using [setTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(int)) / [setTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(android.content.Context,%20int))

for below api level 23

```
setTextAppearance(int res id)
```

From api level 23

```
setTextAppearance (Context context, int resId)


TextView textView = new TextView(PhotoActivity.this);
        textView.setText("Photo not found.");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
            textView.setTextAppearance(PhotoActivity.this, R.style.yourTextViewStyleResourceID);
            /*
            * To give font style Bold Italic I would suggest you check this answer
            * https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200841
            * */
        } else {
            textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.yourTextViewStyleResourceID);
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Its also possible to give style without checking sdk version

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textViewObject, R.style.yourTextViewStyleResourceID);
```

To give font style Bold Italic I would suggest you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200841)

Comment: As @JorgeCastillo [notes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39247670/295028), you can avoid the version check by using TextViewCompat:

`TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(statusLinkTextView, R.style.YourTextAppearanceStyle);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following links :

[How to change a TextView's style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime)

and

[Set TextView style (bold or italic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic)

Good luck .