# Add TextView at runtime in Adapter

Tags: java, android

append every message in array

> m.getGenre()

as new message with TextView for every message in array i want to make TextView  for it and append

this is CustomListAdapter inside it i want loop in array and append every item in array as new TextView

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<notofication> movieItems;
private final Context context;


public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<notofication> movieItems,Context c) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);


    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    final notofication m = movieItems.get(position);







    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());



    // rating
    rating.setText(String.valueOf(m.getRating()));


    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
       //append every str as new textView
    }


    // release year
    year.setText(m.getYear());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

now the result will be something like this (its just example)

[image]

how can i make new textView for every message like this image

[image]

this is my code

```
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
       //append every str as new textView
    }
```

but i dont know how to make new TextView adn append it inside CustomAdapter

Comment: make `genre` as `LinearLayout` and create `textView` at `runtime` and add to the textview to the `genre` .......

Comment: @sushildlh  any example I am beginner in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this example

instead of this........

```
TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
```

use this

```
LinearLayout mgenre = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
```

**Note:-in xml change TextView of id genre into Linear Layout with orientation vertical.**

```
for(String genre:m.getGenre()){
    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    text.setLayoutParams(p);
    text.setText(genre);
    text.setTextAppearance(R.style.boldText);

    mgenre.addView(text);
}
```

enjoy coding...........

Comment: how to add style to new TextView ?

Comment: have look on edit answer or go through this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919173/android-set-textview-textstyle-programmatically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime

Comment: LinearLayout genrxe = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rrr);
for(int i =0 ; i < 17;i++){

            TextView text = new TextView(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            text.setLayoutParams(p);
            text.setText("your message here"+ i);

            genrxe.addView(text);
        }

no thing shown in the linearLayout !!

Comment: what is size of linear layout in xml ?

Comment: width 189dp and height 509dp and background red its just a test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114939/discussion-between-sushildlh-and--).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `TextView` programatically by,

```
TextView textView=new TextView(context);
```

To add it as a list view item I would suggest you to create a holder in your `list_row` XML

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/holder"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:width="match_parent"
     android:height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then attach the text views to it.

```
 LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.holder);

 for(String genre:m.getGenre()){
    TextView tv=new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setText(genre);
    //set a dummy color to check whether views are added
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    //set more styles to the text view if you want
    ll.addView(tv);
}
```

Comment: i will try it now  :)

Comment: you have to set LayoutParams  like this :  LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    text.setLayoutParams(p);

Comment: Updated the answer