# How can I set a textview's style programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I add a style to a textview in java? I am trying to add one under my values/styles.xml, not to add each attribute individually.

```
LinearLayout messagesLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.messages_layout);
TextView sentOne = new TextView(this);
sentOne.setText(sentMessage);

messagesLayout.addView(sentOne);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find [this answer by Benjamin Piette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613069/2988879) handy. To change this into working code for a TextView just change it up a bit:

```
TextView tv = new TextView (new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.mystyle), null, 0);
```

EDIT: to set other things like margins, height & width and others, use LayoutParams. To set the params [throrin19's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728484/2988879) can be helpful.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I've looked at that answer. The issue I have with it is that it does not copy over layou_margin, layout weight, and layout_height among others. I've defined all those in styles

Comment: You can (should) define those in LayoutParams

Answer (score -1):

There is an answer for this already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919203/5544859

```
textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

to preserve the previously set typeface attributes you can use:

```
textview.setTypeface(textview.getTypeface(), Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Credit to: @Raz

Comment: Sorry, but that answer is for textstyle (bold, italic, normal). I am asking about style (all other attributes).