# How do I set different font sizes to a string (that is highlighted, underlined) in a textview

Tags: android, textview, string-formatting

I am displaying text in a textview without using toString(), to keep the formatting(bold, underline, italics) within the text. But now I want to set different font sizes to `_etheadertext` ,`_etheadertext3`  etc..

```
String header = _etheadertext.getText() + "\n" + _etheadertext3.getText() + "\n" + _etheadertext4.getText() + "\n" + _etheadertext5.getText();
```

Comment: It's span feature https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans , but this may be the one for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919173/android-set-textview-textstyle-programmatically

Comment: It doesn't answer my questions. I can't put set typeface because it's not a textview

Comment: Please upload layout xml or show which class you are using for _etheadertext etc. You've wrote "I m displaying text in a textview" in the question. Isn't it  a textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use text [**Spans**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans) to apply formatting to parts of a string.

```
SpannableString spannablecontent=new SpannableString(content.toString());
//set a Style Span to apply Typeface style    
spannablecontent.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), 
                             0,spannablecontent.length(), 0);
```

You can set [**RelativeSizeSpan**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan) to change the text sizes if required.

And then finally, set the spanned string in a TextView.

```
mTextView.setText(spannablecontent);
```