# applying themes to my android app dynamically

Tags: android, themes

I have three buttons to change themes. On clicking each button my app theme must change dynamically. How to do it programmatically.

Comment: Sorry but you can't change style programmatically, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246447/how-to-set-the-style-attribute-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: have a look at [this](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)

Answer (score 2):

To set the theme dynamically at runtime, call setTheme() in your activity's onCreate() method, before calling setContentView(). To change the theme, you simply need to restart your activity.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html) on how dynamically apply themes.

and [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) one too.

Answer (score 0):

Please Visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for it.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

By defining an xml theme file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can also apply styles to all activities of an application:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Or just one activity:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: How can i change my background color when i click button

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can't change styles programmatically.

[how to set the Style Attribute Programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246447/how-to-set-the-style-attribute-programmatically-in-android)

There are certainly other methods to achieve this desired behavior however. You could set onclick listeners for each button, and programmatically change text size, color, background etc of your various view elements

Answer (score 0):

you can use a particular theme for a given xml file.
in graphical layout you can CHANGE the theme of the layout using editing config.

use onclick event to go to next layout and here your theme will be different from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Vimalatha, to change your background when you click a button just add this code to the onClick function of your button.

```
 myLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Assuming that myLinearLayout is your LinearLayout name...