# Programmatically added TextInputLayout not showing the Outline Box

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, android-textinputlayout, programmatically-created

Adding TextInputLayout with TextInputEditText Programmatically not showing the Outline Box

I want to display some editable fields in a fragment. If I use the below xml then my fragment displayed TextInputLayout with a box outline as expected

sample_layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/clParent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glvHoldLabelTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".05"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glhHoldLabelStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glhHoldLabelEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilUsername"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/glhHoldLabelEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/glhHoldLabelStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/glvHoldLabelTop">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tietUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the output from sample_layout.xml [TextInputLayout from XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkUvB.png)

---

But when I try to do the same through program, it is not showing the outline box and the theme used by the TextInputLayout is also different

Code:

```
        TextInputLayout tilUsername = new TextInputLayout(getActivity(), null, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox);


        TextInputEditText edtUsername = new TextInputEditText(getActivity());
        tilUsername.addView(edtUsername);

//        Set Layout parameters
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams clpTextInputLayout = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        clpTextInputLayout.topToTop = glvHoldLabelTop.getId();
        clpTextInputLayout.topMargin = 50;
        clpTextInputLayout.setMarginStart(100);
        clpTextInputLayout.setMarginEnd(100);
        tilUsername.setLayoutParams(clpTextInputLayout);
        tilUsername.setHint("Username");
        tilUsername.setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);
        tilUsername.setBoxCornerRadii(5, 5, 5, 5);

//        Add TextInputlayout to ConstraintLayout
        clParent.addView(tilUsername);
```

Here is the output from code:
[TextInputLayout from Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG6zo.png)

**Note:**
Build.gradle(:app) has the below dependency added

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'

Please correct what I am missing here?

Comment: @MikeM. setBoxBackgroundMode call is already there. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001705) the output TextInputLayout has box outline. I am following the same approach, but the result I am getting is different

Comment: Oh, whoops. Sorry, I don't know how I missed that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what’s causing this issue. In `style.xml` file, changing the `parent` attribute of `AppTheme` style from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

displayed the outline box. Now I can see the expected output in my TextInputLayout. Thought it would help someone who is facing the same issue. But still I am not sure about the impact of changing the AppTheme. Suggestions are welcome!

**Edit:**

I had to modify the method which initializes and adds TextInputLayout to the parent layout as well. Below are my findings,

```
    TextInputLayout tilUsername = new TextInputLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox));

//    Set Box related configurations first before adding TextInputEditText to the TextInputLayout
    tilUsername.setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);
    tilUsername.setBoxBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(tilUsername.getContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
    tilUsername.setHint("Username");

//    Set Layout parameters
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams clpTextInputLayout = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tilUsername.setLayoutParams(clpTextInputLayout);
    clpTextInputLayout.topToTop = glvHoldLabelTop.getId();
    clpTextInputLayout.topMargin = 50;
    clpTextInputLayout.setMarginStart(100);
    clpTextInputLayout.setMarginEnd(100);

//    Add TextInputEditText to TextInputLayout
    TextInputEditText edtUsername = new TextInputEditText(tilUsername.getContext());
    tilUsername.addView(edtUsername);

//    Call this line after adding TextInputEditText to the TextInputLayout to get rid error 'float com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.getTopLeftCornerResolvedSize()' on a null object reference'
    tilUsername.setBoxCornerRadii(50, 50, 50, 50);


//    Add TextInputlayout to ConstraintLayout
    clParent.addView(tilUsername);
```

---

**Here is the final output:**

[image: Final Output]

Comment: Yes, whenever you use Material Components you have to do that, I just checked the images and saw that the one which is added programmatically is the stock one and not the material one which obviously means that it was not getting the OutLined material theme. Good that you've figured it out yourself. Removed that downvote.