# Custom TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I want to have my `CustomTextInputLayout` to have `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` as default style **without defining it anywhere in the XML**.

I tried this

```kotlin
class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox), attrs, defStyleAttr) {

}
```

and this

```kotlin
class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
```

but it's not working. I've tried the default XML way

```xml
<com.custom.CustomTextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    ...>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        ...
        android:hint="Sample Hint" />
</com.custom.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

and it's working.

- What am I missing here?
- How can I set a default style for custom `TextInputLayout` without using `XML`?

Comment: That's a style, not a theme, which is why it doesn't work as expected with the `ContextThemeWrapper`. `TextInputLayout` now has publicly available methods to set that background, however, as described in the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001705). You could just do that instead, in your custom `View`'s initial setup.

Comment: @MikeM. I've tried that, but as shown in the [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2stI.png), the top left corners getting damaged. The XML way would work, but my requirement is to do it without XML.

Comment: I can't reproduce that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3T2G.png. Which version of Material Components are you using?

Comment: I am using `v1.3.0-alpha01`, and here's the [reproducible link](https://github.com/theapache64/52989087)

Comment: Well, in the Kotlin class, apparently that won't work in an `init()` block, even with the `post()`. You'll have to do it from explicit constructors. The Java one works if you get rid of the `ContextThemeWrapper`s, and add the `setBoxBackgroundMode()` where needed. Keep in mind that `View`s inflated from layout XML are instantiated with the two-parameter constructor, so make sure that you call it there, at least, since you're not chaining your constructors.

Comment: Yeah. I believe the `@JvmOverload` would generate each constructor. Thanks for looking into it @Mike

Comment: Yeah, it does, but you can't add any of your own code in the shorthand form, so you'll need to spell out the necessary constructors.

Comment: Got it. Maybe you can add an with all these findings,so that it'd help someone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216254/discussion-between-theapache64-and-mike-m).

Answer (score -1):

It is not exactly what you are looking for.
You can define:

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.textInputStyle
) : TextInputLayout(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Outlined_Theme), attrs, defStyleAttr) { ...  }
```

with:

```
<style name="Outlined.Theme" parent="">
      <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout juse use:

```
 <com.example.quicksample.CustomTextInputLayout
       ....
       android:hint="Sample">

       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText../>

 </com.example.quicksample.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Your code doesn't work because `ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox`) the 2nd parameter has to be an attribute theme and not a style (it is the same for `TextInputLayout(context, attrs, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)`)