# OutlinedBox of TextInputLayout is not showing programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a CustomTextInputLayout class and set the style to Resource.Style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox and BoxBackgroundMode to BoxBackgroundOutline but the OutlinedBox is still not showing. I'm using Xamarin.Android.

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout : TextInputLayout
{
    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) : base(context, null, Resource.Style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
    {
        Init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs, Resource.Style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
    {
        Init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        Init(context);
    }

    public void Init(Context context)
    {
        var textInputEditText = new TextInputEditText(context) { LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(-1, -2) };
        AddView(textInputEditText);
        BoxBackgroundMode = BoxBackgroundOutline;
    }
}
```

This is the content_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <MaterialTest.CustomTextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the AppTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

This is what it looks like (no OutlinedBox):
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify your code, you can take a look the following code:

```
 public class CustomTextInputLayout : TextInputLayout
{
    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) : base(context, null, Resource.Style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
    {
        Init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs, Resource.Style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
    {
        Init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        Init(context);
    }

    public void Init(Context context)
    {
        SetBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BoxBackgroundOutline);
        SetBoxCornerRadii(5, 5, 5, 5);
        BoxStrokeColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;            
        Hint = "Please Enter Email Address";
        var textInputEditText = new TextInputEditText(context);
        
        AddView(textInputEditText);
        
    }
}

 <textinputlayout.CustomTextInputLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The screenshot:

[image]

But I suggest you can use TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText in xml.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/userIDTextInputLayout"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/boxcolor"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText 
    android:id="@+id/userIDTextInputEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hint="Enter User Name" 
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

You can also add TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText by code behind.

```
  private LinearLayout linearlayout1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        linearlayout1 = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

        TextInputLayout emailTextInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this, null, Resource.Style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox);

        emailTextInputLayout.Hint = "Please Enter Email Address";
        emailTextInputLayout.SetBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BoxBackgroundOutline);
        emailTextInputLayout.SetBoxCornerRadii(5, 5, 5, 5);
        TextInputEditText edtEmail = new TextInputEditText(emailTextInputLayout.Context);
        emailTextInputLayout.AddView(edtEmail);
        linearlayout1.AddView(emailTextInputLayout);

    }
```

You need to add `android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"` firstly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

One thread that you can also take a look:

[How to create TextInputLayout with OutlineBox programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989087/how-to-create-textinputlayout-with-outlinebox-programmatically)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You are right, it is better to use XML. I am using XML+LayoutInflater now and it works fine!