# Layout weight on dynamically added RemoteViews

Tags: java, android, android-layout, remoteview

Within my widget, i'm using the following to dynamically add items (R.layout.widget_item) to a LinearLayout defined within my main widget layout:

```
//--  Main widget layout
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_design);

//--  Add to main layout
RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
views.addView(R.id.view_container, newView);
```

My question is, how can I dynamically set the "android:layout_weight" attribute on the newView?

Comment: see [this][1] link plz.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224193/set-the-layout-weight-of-a-textview-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

newView in your example is an instance of class RemoteViews and I don't think you can easily set anything above and beyond what RemoteViews provides.

```
newView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

The above will not work because it's not part of RemoteViews.

As far as I can see... there may be some round about way of setting and finding dimensions and other layoutParams of RemoteViews, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Good point, unfortunately there does not seem to be any sort of workaround. LayoutParams isn't a Java type like an Integer to String so you cannot use the set* methods that involve reflection on it either.

Answer (score -1):

first you get the view params like this

```
layoutParams = newView.getParams();
```

then edit tham
//layoutParams .setThis/setThat all kinds of manipulations you want to do

and then set the new params back to the view

```
newView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot seem to get this to work, the following line displays an error: `code`LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) newView.getParams();`code`  any ideas?

Comment: I guess newView it is not in any LinearLayout

Answer (score -1):

layout_weight is part of the LinearLayout.LayoutParams that you apply to a the LinearLayout, not the LinearLayout itself.  There's a constructor that takes a third param representing the layout_weight.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight