# How to dynamically set height and width of an ImageView in an Android widget to "match_parent"?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview

There is one `ImageView` in my homescreen widget. In the layout file, I am setting the height and width to `wrap_content`. But depending on user's input, I have to change its height and width to `match_parent`. How can this be done ?

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
```

Now I tried to use the `setInt()` method on this `RemoteViews` object like this to just check if it is possible to change height and width:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.widgetImageView, "setMinimumHeight", 300);
```

But this is what I get on the logcat:

```
couldn't find any view, using error view
android.widget.ImageView can't use method with RemoteViews: setMinimumHeight(int)
```

So how do I change its height and width to `match_parent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering how this can be done, I used two `ImageView` in the layout. One with height and width set to `wrap_content` and another with height and width set to `match_parent`. Depending on the user's input, I called the `setVisibility` to hide the `ImageView` which was not required through `RemoteView`.

```
rv.setInt(R.id.widgetImageView1, "setVisibility", View.GONE);
```

There are a very few `ImageView` methods which we can call through `RemoteView`.

Comment: Changing view visibility in `RemoteViews` could be done a little bit easier with dedicated method: `rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.widgetImageView1, View.GONE)`

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
    ImageView view = new ImageView();
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

First parameter of `LayoutParams` is for width, second for height.

Here, I have created a new ImageView for explanation. You should use your own ImageView variable from your code, to do the above. I hope that's clear.

[Update to code]: Sorry, the `MATCH_PARENT` variable is under `LayoutParams` not under `View`. I've updated the code.

[Update]: Above answer does not work for `RemoteViews` as `RemoteViews` cannot have Layout Params. Based on the answer given in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373501/layout-weight-on-dynamically-added-remoteviews), there is no way to set or find dimensions for RemoteViews by normal methods.

I found this [Android Widget Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html#overview_size), where under the section Widget Size, the author says:

```
    A Widget will take a certain amount of cells on the homescreen. A cell is
    usually used to display the icon of one application. As a calculation rule 
    you should define the size of the widget with the formula: 

    ((Number of columns / rows)* 74) - 2. 

    These are device independent pixels and the -2 is used to avoid rounding issues.

    As of Android 3.1 a Widgets can be flexible in size, e.g. the user can make it
    larger or smaller. To enable this for Widgets you can use the 
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical" attribute in the XML configuration file
    for the widget.
```

From this, I can suggest you that instead of setting a specific integer size value directly, why not set the number of rows and columns to resize? For example, if your initial widget size was `4 Columns and 1 Row`, then on user input, you can change it to `4 Columns and 4 Rows`, thus making it occupy the whole screen (Max size for widgets is 4 Rows and 4 Columns)

I know the above method is not what you wanted, but this seems like the only way to me. Try and see if it's helpful.

Comment: That's incorrect! I'm trying to change height and width of an `ImageView` which is `inside a homescreen widget`. Through `RemoteViews` only we can access this `ImageView`.

Comment: Apparently there is no easy way to set dimensions of widgets. Check my updated answer, I've posted the link of a tutorial, and my opinion about how to resize the widget.

Comment: I want to resize the ImageView only and not the whole widget.

Comment: how to give fixed size like 50,50