# in Android layout_weight for Table Rows in dynamic Table

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm dynamically creating Table rows and adding two TextViews into the new Rows. Doing that works fine, but now I'm trying to format the LayoutParams so that the two TextViews have a layout_weight of 1 each. I've tried adding some LayoutParams but it looks like they are being ignored. Here's my code for creating the rows, and I've commented out the LayoutParams bit, and there is no change when I run the app, which says to me that the LayoutParams are being ignored. **I need some help assigning layout_weight to the two TextViews so that in my row-creating code I can achieve this**:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

So here's my code to create the rows:

```
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.pres_table);

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < pres_res.size(); ctr++)

    {
        final String pst_str = pres_res.get(ctr);
        final String yrs_str = yrs_res.get(ctr);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        /*
        TableRow.LayoutParams trPara = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int leftMargin = 10;
        int topMargin = 2;
        int rightMargin = 10;
        int bottomMargin = 2;
        trPara.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trPara);

         */
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(pst_str);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv1.setTextSize(18);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(yrs_str);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv2.setTextSize(18);

        tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
```

and the XML to create the Table is basic like this:

```
            <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/pres_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >
        </TableLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see your commented out `LayoutParams` lines, but I don't see `weight` anywhere. Either way, you want to set the weight to the TextViews, not the TableRows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks to Geobits for setting me on the right path and letting me know I had the LayoutParams calls in the wrong place. They need to be applied to the TextView, not the Table Row. Then based on that, I found a StackOverflow posting: [Set the layout weight of a TextView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224193/set-the-layout-weight-of-a-textview-programmatically) where the second answer was the solution for me. So now my code looks like this and it works the way I want it:

```
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.pres_table);

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < pres_res.size(); ctr++)

    {
        final String pst_str = pres_res.get(ctr);
        final String yrs_str = yrs_res.get(ctr);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        /*
        TableRow.LayoutParams trPara = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int leftMargin = 10;
        int topMargin = 2;
        int rightMargin = 10;
        int bottomMargin = 2;
        trPara.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trPara);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

         */
        LayoutParams tvPar = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(tvPar);
        tv1.setText(pst_str);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv1.setTextSize(18);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setLayoutParams(tvPar);
        tv2.setText(yrs_str);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv2.setTextSize(18);

        tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
```

Right under the commented out bit is the solution showing the new `LayoutParams tvPar` code.

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this way
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
        tv1.setText(pst_str);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv1.setTextSize(18);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
        tv2.setText(yrs_str);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv2.setTextSize(18);

        tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how can it be done, thanks for your help. Why did you use ViewGroup?