# Using MvvmCross to Bind to layout_width and layout_height

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Is it possible to use MvvmCross to bind the height of an object to a property in the viewmodel?

```
<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/blue_cat_icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
local:MvxBind="layout_height User.Height; layout_width User.Width" />
```

Xamarin studio complains if there's no layout_height or layout_width defined, so I'm hoping there's a way to override a property through binding.

I have five icons and I only want one of them to be larger based on a property of the VM, I also assume I'll be using a value converter.

[image: meowmeowbeenz]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the approach to take for this would be similar to the approach in [How to bind to View's layout_weight in MvvmCross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477431/how-to-bind-to-views-layout-weight-in-mvvmcross)

#### 1. Add a Type for your scaling - e.g.

```
public class Scaling
{
    public double Height {get; private set;}
    public double Width {get; private set;}

    // ctor
}
```

#### 2. Add a property for that type too

```
public Scaling CurrentScaling
{
    get { return _scaling; }
    set { _scaling = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentScaling); }
}
```

#### 3. In the view project add a custom binding that knows about Scaling

```
public class ViewScalingCustomBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    public ViewScalingCustomBinding(object target) : base(target)
    {
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof (Scaling); }
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var realTarget = target as View;
        if(target == null)
            return;

        var scaling = value as Scaling;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParameters = realTarget.LayoutParameters;
        realTarget.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(scaling.Width, scaling.Height);
    }
}
```

#### 4. In the view project register the custom binding that knows about Scaling

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>(
                    "ScaleMe", 
                    v => new ViewScalingCustomBinding(v) );
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
}
```

#### 5. Use the binding

```
local:MvxBind="ScaleMe CurrentScaling"
```

---

Note:

- the Type used for `LayoutParameters` is container dependent - in this code above I used `LinearLayout`
- none of this code above is tested - but the general approach should work
- if you are using API 11 or greater, then another approach is to use Android `View`'s `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties - that's what I'd prefer to use.