# Android: How to Remove an object from xml programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

In my app I have a `AdView` object and **Float button** in a `LinearLayout` (Vertical). And I want when the user buys the in-app-purchase **"Remove ads"** to remove the `AdView` object from the xml so the FAB button take its place. Like this:

[image: ads]

no ads:

[image]

How can I do that ? 
That is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myMainRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar">
</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    />

<TextView android:id="@+id/list_empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="No Shopping Items yet"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        fab:show_animation="@anim/fab_roll_from_down"
        fab:hide_animation="@anim/fab_roll_to_down"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code that removes the adview:

```
mIsRemoveAdds = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_REMOVE_ADDS);
            if(!mIsRemoveAdds) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"no premium",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }else{

                if(mAdView != null) {
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"premium",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

### [image]

Comment: did u try View.GONE?

Comment: you can show hide view using `yourbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and set the width & height of layout to 0

Comment: I tried this but when I installed the app on a device that already had purchased the "remove ads" feature the adview was gone, but there is still space bellow the Float button.

Comment: If you using View.INVISIBLE, then space will be remain. if  View.GONE then space should not be there.

Comment: mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        params.weight = 1.0f;
                        actionButton.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: @NullByte I am using GONE, but the space is still there :/

Comment: Its not proper solution but use any container for AdView and hide that container, Like FrameLayout or LinearLayout anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove any view you can use, where `ll` is your parent linear layout

```
ll.removeView(view)// to remove particular view
ll.removeViewAt(position);// to remove view from particular position
```

Alternatively you can also set `visibility` of your adView to `GONE` which will in result give its place to the button.

```
adButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**EDIT:**
After looking at your XML I think its weight which is creating the issue.
You should set `floatingButton` `layout_weight` to 100 where you are hiding the `adView`

```
floatingButton.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100f));
```

**EDIT:**
I would suggest not to use weights as you don't need them.

Comment: I tried this but when I installed the app on a device that already had purchased the "remove ads" feature the adview was gone, but there is still space bellow the Float button.

Comment: I think its problem with the layout_weight, you should also set the weight of floatingButton to 100 while removing adView - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224365/3828908 for weight

Comment: I still have problem, setting the layout_weight of my button to 100 :/

Comment: Whats the problem, code doesn't executes or what? Tried using 100.0f?

Comment: No, it just does not work, the space is there.Maybe I am importing the wrong class for the LayoutParams, because android studio is offering me many options. I chose android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Comment: Goto Mobile Settings -> Developer Options -> Show layout bounds. This will draw blue rectangles on every UI component for all applications. Post your app screenshot after that. http://tysmith.me/post/27035355999/layoutbounds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81486/discussion-between-salmaan-and-georgi-koemdzhiev).

Comment: I was able to fix the problem based on the suggestions that you made. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not practical to add the view in xml if you want to dynamically determine whether or not to display it. If you still want to add to add to xml you can just make it invisible or detach/remove the view. Else, don't add the AdView in Xml. I handle this scenario as follows:

```
        adView = new MoPubView(this.getApplicationContext());
        adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.mopub_banner_adunitid));
        adView.refreshDrawableState();
        adView.setBannerAdListener(this);
        if(!Prefs.getUserPreferenceBooleanValue(Prefs.Key.REMOVE_ADS_PAID, this)) {
              frameLayout.addView(adView, bannerViewLayoutParams);      
              adView.loadAd();

        }
```

Add the adview programatically in your code. Store a flag in shared preferences and set it as required to display or remove ads. when the activity loads, read the flag and determine whether or not to add the adview to the layout.

For the size of the button you can sent it to be relative to the available space or resize it based on the value of flag.

Comment: That is interesting approach, I will be definitely checking it out. Thanks!

Comment: to add to the above, You could even choose to not instantiate the object at all by putting the entire code in the if block. This will use a tiny tiny bit less memory. Not a major difference but better. I have some other reason for doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

lets say **youViewName** is the view you want to remove.
if its a **LinearLayout** use below code, otherwise if its a **RelativeLayout** replace **LinearLayout** in the below code by **RelativeLayout**

```
((LinearLayout) youViewName.getParent()).removeView(youViewName);
```

In your case the line below should work

```
((LinearLayout) mAdView.getParent()).removeView(mAdView);
```