# Android : buttons go off the edge of the screen

Tags: android, button, tablerow

I have a table layout inside a linear layout 
after inflating 3 buttons in the table row the last button go off screen
I mean the 3 buttons don't fit the screen width
what should i do?

here is the code

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TableRow doesn't check if it's content fit the Screen Size. I guess your Buttons take all of the Space and therefore the last Buttons is outside of the Screen.

I can think of 2 Solutions for this issue:

- Use a LinearLayout with weights for each Button:

  ```
  <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <Button
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_margin="8dp"
              android:layout_weight="1.0" />

          <Button
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_margin="8dp"
              android:layout_weight="1.0" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

  You can do this programmatically too of course.
  More about weights can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html
- Use a Flow-Layout. It automatically checks if your Views fit in the current line and places them in the next if there is not enough space. A good Open Source Library I use myself is this one: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: The think is that I'm using Layout Inflator service and I can't add the buttons like you said
and the text of the buttons are diffrent (in lenght ) everytime that I launch the app(i pick some random text from a string array) - like a quiz

Comment: As I said you can also do this programmatically. See this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224193/set-the-layout-weight-of-a-textview-programmatically