# Why I can not set a custom size for my relativeLayout object

Tags: android

In the following code , Why I can not set a custom size for my `relativeLayout` object? The resolution of my device is 240 * 320.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
            super.onCreate(bundle);
    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.getLayoutParams().width=240;
        relativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height=320;
    setContentView(relativeLayout);}
```

Comment: Why not use MATCH_PARENT?

Comment: I can use the `match_parent`. But I want a scientific reason for this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224193/set-the-layout-weight-of-a-textview-programmatically and make sure your screen size is in fact 240px (and not dp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use a layout parameter like this:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
//You can put the background in another color to check were is the layout
//relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(240, 320);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

setContentView(relativeLayout);
```